# Full Video Not Rendering

Tags: rendering, video

I am trying to render a (pre-made) YouTube intro using Blender but for some reason parts of the top and bottom are getting cut off. I did not change any settings except for bumping the resolution up to 1080p30 and changing the video format to H.264 (I also tried AVI and neither worked. Any help is appreciated. 
[image: video output]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a .blend demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: Without access to a screen capture or blend file, it looks like the video source is overplayed on a particle background? If so the video source seems to be letterboxed, that is there are black borders top and bottom. Your source maybe 16:9 media matted into a 4:3 (sort of square) frame. If that is the case you have not much option but to enlarge the video source to eliminate the borders.